# Using arrow keys with jQuery scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto, arrow-keys

I have successfully implemented the scrollTo jQuery plugin which scrolls to the next div with the class "new" when a link is clicked. However, I would also like to be able to use the arrow keys to scroll up and down to the next/previous divs of the same class.

I have looked all over the internet but have been unable to find out how to do this. I am very new to JS so very simple instructions would be appreciated!

Here is the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){

 $('<div id="next_arrow"></div>') 
  .prependTo("body") //append the Next arrow div to the bottom of the document
  .click(function(){ 
   scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.new').each(function(i, h2){ // loop through article headings
    h2top = $(h2).offset().top; // get article heading top
    if (scrollTop < h2top) { // compare if document is below heading
     $.scrollTo(h2, 800); // scroll to in .8 of a second
     return false; // exit function
    }
   });
  });

});
</script>
```

What do I need to add to this to make the arrow keys work?

Thanks,
Ted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `keydown` event listener to listen for keypresses. You can use this on `&lt;input&gt;` fields and the like. Because keydown events [bubble](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) up the DOM, you can use it on the `document` object to catch any keypress on the page:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    alert("Key pressed: " + evt.keyCode);
  });
});
```

Each keypress has a code. If you use the code above in your web page, you'll see that the key code for the down arrow is 40. You can solo this out using an `if` or `switch` statement in the handler:

```
jQuery(function () {

  $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow
      alert("You pressed down.");
    }
  });

});
```

Now you need to bind in the code that actually jumps to the next heading. I recommend abstracting the code out into a function so you can use it for both keypresses and clicks. Here is the function, together with a variant of your original code that uses it:

```
// Here is the function:

function scrollToNew () {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.new').each(function(i, h2){ // loop through article headings
    h2top = $(h2).offset().top; // get article heading top
    if (scrollTop < h2top) { // compare if document is below heading
      $.scrollTo(h2, 800); // scroll to in .8 of a second
      return false; // exit function
    }
  });
}

// Here is your original code, modified to use the function:

jQuery(function () {

  $("#next").click(scrollToNew);

});
```

Finally, you can add in the keypress code and call the function from there:

```
function scrollToNew () {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.new').each(function(i, h2){ // loop through article headings
    h2top = $(h2).offset().top; // get article heading top
    if (scrollTop < h2top) { // compare if document is below heading
      $.scrollTo(h2, 800); // scroll to in .8 of a second
      return false; // exit function
    }
  });
}

jQuery(function () {

  $("#next").click(scrollToNew);

  $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevents the usual scrolling behaviour
      scrollToNew(); // scroll to the next new heading instead
    }
  });

});
```

**Update:** To scroll upwards, do two things. Change the `keydown` handler to:

```
  $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow
      evt.preventDefault(); // prevents the usual scrolling behaviour
      scrollToNew(); // scroll to the next new heading instead
    } else if (evt.keyCode == 38) { // up arrow
      evt.preventDefault();
      scrollToLast();
    }
  }
```

and write a `scrollToLast()` function based off of `scrollToNew()` that finds the last new heading that isn't on the page:

```
function scrollToLast () {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  var scrollToThis = null;

  // Find the last element with class 'new' that isn't on-screen:
  $('.new').each(function(i, h2) {
    h2top = $(h2).offset().top;
    if (scrollTop > h2top) {
      // This one's not on-screen - make a note and keep going:
      scrollToThis = h2;
    } else {
      // This one's on-screen - the last one is the one we want:
      return false;
    }
  });

  // If we found an element in the loop above, scroll to it:
  if(scrollToThis != null) {
    $.scrollTo(scrollToThis, 800);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! What would I have to add to be able to use the arrow keys up?

Answer (score 1):

Just for giving more idea, working with arrays.

```
var panel_arr = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.parallax-panel-wrapper').each(function(i, element){ 
        panel_arr.push( $(this).attr("id") );
    });

    var current_parallax_panel_no   = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 40) { // down arrow
            evt.preventDefault(); // prevents the usual scrolling behaviour
            if(current_parallax_panel_no < (panel_arr.length-1)) current_parallax_panel_no++;
            scrollByArrowKeys(1);               
        } else if (evt.keyCode == 38) { // up arrow
            evt.preventDefault(); // prevents the usual scrolling behaviour
            if(current_parallax_panel_no >= 1) current_parallax_panel_no--;
            scrollByArrowKeys(0); 
        }
    });

    function scrollByArrowKeys(add_more){
        scrollToThis = (($("#" + panel_arr[current_parallax_panel_no]).offset().top)  + add_more ; // get element top
        $.scrollTo(scrollToThis, 800);      
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the keypress event and decide which keycode was pressed

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) { 
        case 37:
            //left arrow pressed
        break;
        case 39:
            //right arrow pressed
        break;
    }
});
```